# Move ctor needed for array member of class

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, move-semantics

I want to have a class with an array member ("C-array") of another class that has neither a copy nor a move constructor. Unfortunately the compiler gives me an error message that tells me that the inner class's move constructor was required. I do not understand why the move is required for an array with given size at compile time. Even more strange to me is, that the compiler does NOT complain, when the array is not a class member but an automatic stack variable.
The following code illustrates my problem. It compiles and runs as expected WITH the first line (i.e with move constructor), the output shows that the move constructor is NOT called. But with the first line commented out, I get an error message in line 27 (array as another struct's member variable), whereas line 37 (array as stack variable) still compiles.
Please note that I would like to use initializer lists to construct the array elements of type A as in the example.

```
#define WITH_MOVE_CTOR

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  A(int i, bool b) : mi(i), mb(b) 
  { }
  A(A&&s)
#ifdef WITH_MOVE_CTOR
  : mi(s.mi),mb(s.mb)
  { cout << s << "move ctor called\n"; }
#else
  = delete;
#endif
  A() = delete;
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & in, const A&a)
  { return in << a.mi << "," << a.mb; }
  void foo() const { cout << *this << " foo called\n"; }
  int mi;
  bool mb;
};

struct CA {
  CA() : m( {{1, true},{2, false}} ) {}
  CA(const A&) = delete;
  CA(A&&) = delete;
  CA& operator=(const CA&) = delete;
  A m[2];
};

int main() 
{
  cout << "C-array:\n";
  A ca[2] = {{1, true},{2, false}};
  ca[1].foo();

  cout << "C-array in struct:\n";
  CA sca;
  sca.m[1].foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C-array:
2,0 foo() called
C-array in struct:
2,0 foo() called
```

Comment: Try braces: `: m { {1, true}, {2, false} {}`

Comment: Omitting the () braces does solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: @Kerrek SB Can you explain what the braces caused the compiler to do instead? At least at run time the result is the same, i. e. move constructor is NOT called...

Answer (score 1):

Line 37 is a static initializer, so it's constructing in place.  So no need to move anything.

Line 27 is allocating the array first, then moving the initializer array.  This requires a move constructor.

Comment: Why is l. 37 a "static" initializer? There is no "static" storage type specifier, so the array should be "allocated" on stack with the array size known at compile time (i.e. the compiler can reserve memory on stack as for any none-array stack variable, the heap is not involved). Same is true for l. 37. Please also note, that at run time no move constructor is called, i. e.  in place construction is indeed done in l. 37 and l. 27.

Answer (score 0):

I have just learned from Kerrek SB, that the () braces around the initializer list in the CA ctor (l. 37) caused the problem, thank you!
But still one open question remains: What do the ()  braces in l. 37 of my example mean to the compiler? At  run time they have obviously no effect when the move constructor exists, since it is NOT called.